# concerning the connection of my MySQL server to jupyter notebook

Tags: python, mysql, jupyter-notebook

I have been trying to create a simple notebook-styled portfolio for my SQL projects. until now I have gotten stuck with the connection part as I cant connect my MySQL database to my jupyter notebook. I will give out the code below for more details.

```
!pip install ipython-sql pymysql
!pip install sqlalchemy
!pip install mysql-connector-python
!pip install pymysql

%load_ext sql

%sql mysql+mysqlconnector://root:password@localhost:3306/mavenfuzzyfactory
```

I have used all these packages that I think are needed for connecting to the database
btw the mavenfuzzyfactory is the name of my schema in MySQL workbench (the icon is like a cylinder with multiple tires since I use the latest version 8.x).

NOTE: i intend to use %%sql in my notebook

Comment: And what happens when you execute the above code? Is sql magic properly configured for jupyter notebook? Did you try using mysql+pymysql as the driver?

Comment: when i ran the code it gave me this error:

(mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError) 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306' (99)
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/4xp6)
Connection info needed in SQLAlchemy format, example:
               postgresql://username:password@hostname/dbname
               or an existing connection: dict_keys([])